# Delete root element and all children via PHP DOM Document

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to delete all the data of my XML file via PHP DOM Document. Basically, I want the entire XML file to be empty. I am trying to achieve this via DOM Document & XPath.

I am getting errors of

> Undefined property, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function hasChildNodes() and Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in.

Please assist.

**delete.php**

```
<?php 
    $xmlDocument=new DOMDocument;
    $xmlDocument->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
    $xmlDocument->load("person.xml");
    $personXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlDocument);

    $parentNode=$personXPath-> evaluate('person');
        while ($parentNode->hasChildNodes()){
        $parentNode->removeChild($parentNode->childNodes->item(0));
 }

 ?>
```

**person.xml**

```
<person>
    <personN number="8">
        <personL letter="Y">
            <fullname>
                <firstname>Carl</firstname>
                <lastname>Steel</lastname>
            </fullname>
            <appearance>
                <eye>brown</eye>
            </appearance>
        </personL>  
    </personN>
  <personN number="9">
        <personL letter="Z">
            <fullname>
                <firstname>Paul</firstname>
                <lastname>Steel</lastname>
            </fullname>
            <appearance>
                <eye>blue</eye>
            </appearance>
        </personL>  
    </personN>
</person>
```

Comment: If you simply want to empty the file, why not simply `file_put_contents('person.xml', '');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixing the Code

Several errors in your code:

1. Your xpath should be `"//person"` instead of just `"person"`.
2. `$personXPath->evaluate()` ([DOMXPath::evaluate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php)) returns [DOMNodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), which is an [Interator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) of all the [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) that matches the query. Your code expects it to be a [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) that has a [hasChildNodes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php) method.

So you may change your code to get proper output without error:

```php
<?php

$xmlDocument=new DOMDocument;
$xmlDocument->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$xmlDocument->load("person.xml");
$personXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlDocument);

$parentNodes = $personXPath->evaluate('//person');
foreach ($parentNodes as $parentNode) {
  while ($parentNode->hasChildNodes()){
    $parentNode->removeChild($parentNode->childNodes->item(0));
  }
}

echo $xmlDocument->saveXML();
```

This would effectively remove all child nodes of all `<person>` tags.

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<person/>
```

### Simply remove all `<person>`

But the code above does not remove the `<person>` tags in the XML file. If, for the given XML structure, that you want to remove all `<person>` tags, there is no need to remove child elements of any `<person>` at all:

```php
<?php

$xmlDocument=new DOMDocument;
$xmlDocument->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$xmlDocument->load("person.xml");
$personXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlDocument);

$personNodes = $personXPath->evaluate('//person');
foreach ($personNodes as $personNode) {
  $personNode->parentNode->removeChild($personNode);
}
echo $xmlDocument->saveXML();
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```